# Count selected records in list view on visualforce page

Tags: apex, list-view, custom-controller, visuaforce

I created a Visualforce page rendered as PDF, it has a concatenated header than include info from records selected, but specifically I'm trying to count total records selected. I created a class for apex repeat, sum amount for selected record and count selected records, but count code doesn't work, it shows all records on the list. I need to count only records selected.

Thanks for your help.

Paco

**Controller** code:

```java
public class GenerateResourcePaymenttxt {
    ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon;
    public final npe01__OppPayment__c pay;
    public List<npe01__OppPayment__c> getIDs;
    public String payIds{get;set;} 
    public GenerateResourcePaymenttxt(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller){
        setCon = controller;    
        Set<Id> payIdSet = new Set<Id>();
        for (npe01__OppPayment__c pay :(npe01__OppPayment__c[])setCon.getSelected()){
            payIdSet.add(pay.Id);
        }
    }
    public npe01__OppPayment__c getpay(){
        return pay;
    }
    //COUNT Selected records
    private Integer total;

    public Integer getTotal() {
        total = [SELECT count() FROM npe01__OppPayment__c WHERE npe01__Payment_Method__c = 'Tarjeta de Crédito' AND Estado_de_Pago__c = 'PENDIENTE']; // Example for standard Account objects
        return total;
    }
    //SUM Payment Amount
    public decimal getTotal2()
    {
        Decimal total2=0;
        for(npe01__OppPayment__c pay :(npe01__OppPayment__c[])setCon.getSelected()){
            total2 += pay.npe01__Payment_Amount__c;
        }
        return total2;
    }
}
```

**Visulaforce** code:

```html
<apex:page standardController="npe01__OppPayment__c" recordSetVar="pays" extensions="GenerateResourcePaymenttxt" renderAs="pdf" applyBodyTag="false" >
    <apex:relatedList list="npe01__OppPayment__c" />
    <div class="header">
        <div align="left" style="font-family: Verdana;font-size:11px;">
            {!LPAD(TEXT(DAY(TODAY())),2,"0")}{!LPAD(TEXT(MONTH(TODAY())),2,"0")}{!TEXT( YEAR(TODAY()))}{!LPAD(TEXT(HOUR(TIMENOW())+6),2,"0")}{!LPAD(TEXT(MINUTE(TIMENOW())),2,"0")}{!LPAD(TEXT(SECOND(TIMENOW())),2,"0")}{!RIGHT(LPAD(TEXT(total),6, '0') , 6)}{!RIGHT(LPAD(TEXT(total2),13, '0') , 13)}{!'.00'}
        </div>
    </div>
    <apex:repeat value="{!pays}" var="pay">
        <div style="font-family: Verdana;font-size:11px;"> 
            <apex:outputText value="{!'32494486498'}{!pay.Donante__r.ID_Padrino__c}"></apex:outputText> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<apex:outputText value="{!pay.npe01__Check_Reference_Number__c}"></apex:outputText>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<apex:outputText value="{!RIGHT(LPAD(TEXT(pay.npe01__Payment_Amount__c),11, '0') , 11)}{!'.'}{!RIGHT(LPAD(pay.Padrino_Id__c,6, '0') , 6)}"></apex:outputText>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<br/>
        </div>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: I think you correctly getting selected Ids to `payIdSet`, but afterwards you don't use it anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not filtering the result set by Selected records in your query.

Make the below code changes.

```
public Set<Id> payIdSet{get;set;} // Create a set to store all selected IDs
public GenerateResourcePaymenttxt(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller){
    setCon = controller;    
    for (npe01__OppPayment__c pay :(npe01__OppPayment__c[])setCon.getSelected()){
        payIdSet.add(pay.Id);
    }
}

//COUNT Selected records
private Integer total;

public Integer getTotal() {
    total = [SELECT count() FROM npe01__OppPayment__c WHERE ID IN: payIdSet]; // Filter count by the number of selected records
    return total;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Mohith I made changes, but now don't count records selected

Comment: What is the count you are getting?

Comment: I'm getting 0, I'm using {!RIGHT(LPAD(TEXT(total),6, '0') , 6)} to get count, but it get zero records

Comment: What do you get if you print just total?